# semantic ui Form validation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, semantic-ui

I tried to use the 'Semantic Form Validation' plugin to validate input length, like this:

```
$('.ui.form').form({
    fields: {
        firstname: {
            identifier: 'firstname',
            rules: [{
                type: 'empty',
                prompt: 'Please enter your name'
            }]
        },
        lastname: {
            identifier: 'lastname',
            rules: [{
                type: 'empty',
                prompt: 'Please enter your name'
            }]
        },
        username: {
            identifier: 'username',
            rules: [{
                type: 'minLength[3]',
                prompt: 'Please enter a username'
            }]
        },
        password: {
            identifier: 'password',
            rules: [{
                type: 'minLength[6]',
                prompt: 'Please enter a password'
            }]
        },
        terms: {
            identifier: 'terms',
            rules: [{
                type: 'checked',
                prompt: 'You must agree to the terms and conditions'
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Every single line works just fine but it will not validate `minLength` rule and keep getting error on it. It says

> Form: There is no rule matching the one you specified minLength

Comment: Which version are you on? Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyvk/kdLkfhfb/) that works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been having the same issue today. I tried loads of variations. Then I went and looked for any reference to minLength in the semantic.js source code (and there is nothing there!..). Then I stumbled across function called length

```
length .. // is at least string length
    length: function(value, requiredLength) {
      return (value !== undefined)
        ? (value.length >= requiredLength)
        : false
      ;
    },
```

// so thought i would give that a try and it worked as you would expect..

```
password: {
            identifier: 'password',
            rules: [{
                type: 'length[6]',
                prompt: 'Please enter a password'
            }]
        },
```

// I am using version Semantic UI - 2.0.0.

---

I am still struggling a bit with this features of semantic ui , I cant get the shorthand syntax to work and also cant find a way to have multiple criteria per field.. any suggestions?